# Remove duplicates with case sensitive + additional column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to remove duplicates from one column but also delete data from the row of the column on the left when duplicate is found.
See picture:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNt9A.png)

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates(rngDataColumn As Range)
'assumes rngDataColumn is a column of data

Dim dic As Object
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim varKey As Variant
Dim lngCounter As Long

'create dictionary
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'dictionary becomes case sensitive
dic.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare

'iterate range for unique values
For Each rngCell In rngDataColumn
    If Not dic.Exists(rngCell.Value) Then
        dic.Add Key:=rngCell.Value, Item:=True
    End If
Next rngCell

'clear source range
rngDataColumn.ClearContents

'output unique items - with case sensitivity
lngCounter = 1
For Each varKey In dic.Keys
    rngDataColumn(lngCounter, 1).Value = varKey
    lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
Next varKey

End Sub
```

I found code above and it works for removing duplicates from column G. But I would like to remove corresponding data from column F. 
For example:
If the code finds duplicate in cell G10 it should also delete cell F10.

I tried creating second dictionary as above but I failed.

Could you please correct that code to resolve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

Use it same as you were using your code, it will also delete the values from previous column

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates(rngDataColumn As Range)
'assumes rngDataColumn is a column of data

Dim dic As Object
Dim dic2 As Object
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim varKey As Variant
Dim lngCounter As Long

'create dictionary
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'dictionary becomes case sensitive
dic.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
dic2.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare

'iterate range for unique values
For Each rngCell In rngDataColumn
    If Not dic.Exists(rngCell.Value) Then
        dic.Add Key:=rngCell.Value, Item:=True
        dic2.Add Key:=rngCell.Offset(0, -1).Value & "|" & rngCell.Row(), Item:=True
    End If
Next rngCell

'clear source range
rngDataColumn.ClearContents
rngDataColumn.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents

'output unique items - with case sensitivity
lngCounter = 1

For Each varKey In dic.Keys
    rngDataColumn(lngCounter, 1).Value = varKey
    lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
Next varKey

lngCounter = 1

For Each varKey In dic2.Keys
    rngDataColumn(lngCounter, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value = Split(varKey, "|")(0)
    lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
Next varKey

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but code isn't working. I have got error '457': This key is already associated with an element of this collection in line "dic2.Add Key:=rngCell.Offset(0, -1).Value, Item:=True"

Comment: @sebad90 .. I have amended the code. It should work. Try it

Comment: Glad it Worked :) ... Though it made me work my mind a bit.